# How to get every subject of email with php imap?

Tags: php, gmail, imap

```
<?php
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}';
$username = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$password = 'pass';
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
$nums=imap_num_msg($inbox);
echo  $nums;
for ($i=1;$i<=$nums;$i++){
    $headers = imap_fetchheader($inbox, $i);
    echo  $headers ;}
imap_close($inboxi);
?>
```

With this code I can get the number of all emails in my gmail box.
But it can't print every subject of email in header info. How to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox, $i, 0);
echo $overview[0]->subject . "<BR>";
```

I think it is easier than using imap_fetchheader.

Also, you have an extra 'i' in the last $inbox .

Answer (score 1):

`imap_headerinfo()` and `imap_header()` will help you to get the subject of every email